# Colouring a pm3d surface using a column values

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to colour a splot surface using pm3d and wanted to colour using values from another column instead of the z-axis.

The input file (test.file, tab separated) is :

```
atom_num    residue_name    X   Y   Z
288 1   45.3    36.6    79.3
301 1   38.9    197.4   72.5
314 1   118.2   53.8    76.5
327 1   58.2    139.1   78.5
353 1   1.9 14.4    71.9
366 1   156.9   180.0   72.1
379 1   183.2   5.4 69.5
392 1   71.7    155.4   75.8
457 1   83.4    11.8    74.8
613 1   97.1    180.7   77.5
626 1   145.2   160.3   71.7
678 2   73.1    76.3    81.0
704 3   30.3    46.5    79.3
717 2   216.0   130.7   85.5
743 2   55.0    137.2   74.4
756 2   23.4    67.3    78.3
769 2   46.9    156.1   77.3
821 2   145.4   143.9   80.7
990 2   7.8 119.3   79.8
1016    3   44.3    67.3    76.7
1042    3   12.8    44.4    74.3
1055    3   149.1   79.9    78.2
1068    3   100.8   35.8    76.1
1081    3   57.6    196.8   76.8
1094    3   214.7   122.8   79.5
1107    3   82.0    190.0   74.4
1120    3   150.9   39.4    71.3
1133    3   50.4    143.7   75.3
1146    1   42.9    104.7   74.3
1159    1   139.0   48.8    73.4
1172    1   66.8    165.3   71.5
1198    1   190.7   150.1   84.2
1211    1   92.1    5.1 75.8
1224    1   211.8   177.7   74.1
1237    1   131.6   0.2 73.6
1250    2   103.8   104.2   76.6
1276    2   132.4   5.0 70.0
1289    2   94.4    9.4 73.0
1302    2   72.6    33.7    74.3
1315    2   14.4    162.6   74.7
1406    2   171.4   143.6   86.1
1419    2   209.5   52.9    77.4
1445    2   11.6    14.7    72.3
1458    1   115.5   165.0   73.0
1549    1   147.1   45.5    76.1
1575    1   115.8   36.6    74.5
1588    1   35.8    37.3    76.2
1601    1   65.4    28.2    76.9
1614    1   13.4    199.9   76.5
```

The commands I am using is:

```
set dgrid3d 30,30
set hidden3d
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
splot "test.file" u 3:4:5 w pm3d
```

The image is appearing like this:

[image]

The plot is by default colouring based on the Z-axis value (column 5). I am stuck colouring the plot using the values of Residue Name (column 2), which ranges from 1-3. Is there an option to define which coloumn to choose for colouring? Ideally I would like to have the same plot but coloured according to the column 2, so that I can see which "Residue types" lie in which contours.

Any help would hugely helpful.

Comment: Did you try to save in temporary file one of the two and `splot` both as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557828/plotting-3d-surface-from-scatter-points-and-a-png-on-the-same-3d-graph ?

Comment: I tried the solution suggested there. It didnt work for me.

    gnuplot> set terminal push
    pushed terminal unknown 
    gnuplot> set terminal unknown
    Terminal type set to 'unknown'
    gnuplot> set table "surface.dat"
    gnuplot> set dgrid3d
    gnuplot> splot "4000s.edited" u 3:4:5 w pm3d
    Tabular output of this 3D plot style not implemented

Also, I am unable to understand which to plot first and also what should be the command to incorporate the Column 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `residue` is an integer, it is unclear whether you want it interpolated onto the grid.

However, if that's what you want, you can use the solution in [Plotting 3D surface from scatter points and a png on the same 3D graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557828/plotting-3d-surface-from-scatter-points-and-a-png-on-the-same-3d-graph) but don't use `with pm3d` when writing tables. Here's a solution with a quick and somewhat dirty unix trick to merge the tables:

```
set terminal push #Save current terminal settings
set terminal unknown #dummy terminal
set table "surface.dat"
set dgrid3d
splot 'test.dat' using 3:4:5
set table "residue.dat"
splot 'test.dat' using 3:4:2
unset dgrid3d
unset table
set term pop #reset current terminal settings
!paste surface.dat residue.dat > test_grid.dat
splot "test_grid.dat" u 1:2:3:7 w pm3d
```

Comment: Hi Joce,

The different integers of residue represent different lipid molecules, such as, 1= POPC, 2=POPE, 3=CARDIOLIPIN. I converted them into integers for plotting purpose. Given the surface plot of the layer, I wanted to visualize where different lipid molecules lie on the surface.

Your solution shows the grid but only problem is that the colouring ranges from 1.3-2.1. Is this skipping for the "3" value in the residue column?

Comment: Then I believe regridding is not appropriate, as your column 2 cannot be interpolated. The above answer is a technical answer to the technical problem you brought, and now you are facing a modelling problem rather. If I understand correctly your date, I would e.g. do `splot "data.txt" u 3:4:5:2 w p ps 4 palette pt 7`, possibly with some graphical improvement as the 3D structure may be difficult to appreciate. But that's another question.

Comment: Dear Joce,

Thank you for your reply. The command you gave me `splot "data.txt" u 3:4:5:2 w p ps 4 palette pt 7` gives me the error of `unrecognized plot type`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo ? Try the equivalent `splot "test.dat" u 3:4:5:2 w points pointsize 4 palette pointtype 7`